# How to validation name

Tags: java

I am creating new package programatically through my eclipse plugin project, however, i need to validate the name of the package that user input first. I have written some basic validation code, however, i am looking for any example which cover all the scenarios. I also searched on the web but do not find any example. Even if know the rules for package name (com.xx.....), I will try to implement myself. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plugin has a `JavaConventions` class which has the method:

```
public static IStatus validatePackageName(String name, String sourceLevel, String complianceLevel)
```

which validates a package name. The `sourceLevel` and `complianceLevel` parameters are compiler levels such as "1.3". If you have a `IJavaProject` available you can get these levels with

```
javaProject.getOption(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, true);
javaProject.getOption(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, true);
```

or the defaults with:

```
JavaCore.getOption(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE),
JavaCore.getOption(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE)
```